# What NTFS permissions to choose for secondary partition?

Tags: windows, partitioning, permissions, ntfs

My computer has two disks and two partitions:

1. C: for Windows
2. D: for data

The idea is that `C:` is expendable and can be reimaged quickly. Everything of value is on `D:`.

**What NTFS permissions should I configure for `D:`?** Basically, I want everyone to have full access to that partition because this is a single-user workstation.

I could give `Everyone` full control and replace everything with that. But I do not understand the consequences of doing that.

I ran `AccessEnum.exe` from Sysinternals on `D:` to see what's there. [This looks like right now every user has read and write control.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLdFL.png) I don't see how these settings are different from `Everyone`.

Comment: Everyone is not advised, [see this page](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/23600/potential-consequences-of-using-everyone-to-manage-permissions)

Comment: Also [see this question](http://superuser.com/questions/487015/should-or-shouldnt-i-remove-the-everyone-group-from-my-shared-folders), Actually you could create a shared folder and grant permissions to everyone for that share.